# Android Volley - Persist cache of specific items

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I'm playing around with Volley, and when Volley goes to empty out its cache, I want to persist certain pieces of data (JSON or images), whether in memory or in its DiskBasedCache. Currently what I'm doing is if an item is marked internally as to be persisted, we are saving it to a file, and if Volley fails, then we check for the data in the file.

What I'm currently doing is hacking up DiskBasedCache and holding a static ArrayList of keys not to clear when pruneIfNeeded is called. Is there a more recommended way to doing this?

Answer (score 2):

I think your solution is a good valid option. You have another option which is a little less "hacky" but a little more work:

Create a "layer" above your calls to Volley that has its own disk cache and its own memory cache. Lets call the layer **network interface** for the purpose of this answer.

Follow this flow:

When an network asset is needed:

1. check network layer's mem-cache - return if found.
2. no-hit: check network layer's disk-cache - return if found.
3. no-hit: forward request to Volley.
4. When Volley returns the result, if asset is the kind you want persisted always, persist it in disk and cache.
5. return result.

Every disk operation should be non blocking and performed on a background thread. The whole communication with the network layer should be similar to the Volley style with success and error listeners.